# Replacing upper case letters in Uri to lower case

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm not sure if this is the right location but I'm working with AWS for the first time. I'm trying to update a request Uri to remove all instances of capital letters. As some people connect to my site with them >.<

When replacing my Uri my function is

```
request.uri = request.uri .replace (//cokr//,'') .replace (//\G/,’/g');
```

Have also tried

```
request.uri = request.uri.toLowerCase();
```

Any advice would be appreciated as the first replace works the second doesn't and causes 502 errors. Please help no idea why replacing the string doesn't seem to work like normal.

502 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
The Lambda function result failed validation: The specified URI is in an invalid format.

Comment: Thanks Grynets, however I have already tried .toLowerCase() and it causes the Uri to invalidate itself which is why I have tried to modify each character. In this case     request.uri = request.uri.toLowerCase();

Comment: what language do you use in your lambda function?

Comment: only js works with lambda@edge which is why I'm confused as .toLowerCase() should be a perfectly valid method. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-authoring-functions.html

Comment: Could you please add example of what string do you have and what string would you like to receive? I could help you with some regular expressions, but there might be easier solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by doing all my manipulation on a new string then returning same.

'use strict';

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const request = event.Records[0].cf.request;

```
var cleanPath = "";
cleanPath = request.uri.toLowerCase();
console.log("clean path is : " + cleanPath);
cleanPath = cleanPath.replace('/cokr/','/');

console.log("clean path is now : " + cleanPath);

request.uri = cleanPath;
console.log("request uri is : " + request.uri);

return callback(null, request);
```

};